# Converting string literal to JSON Array and sending using HTTP Post Request

Tags: c++, arduino, http-post

I'm trying to send a post request over an ESP32 WiFi module using an Arduino IDE. Although the response received is 200, I receive a formatting error with the JSON body object. How should I format the JSON object?
Here is what the original JSON object looks like that I need to send:

```
{
 "method":"passthrough",
 "params":{
 "deviceId":"9006765C87CD29BC37447E490C4C91F819143376",
 "requestData":"{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":1}}}"
 }
}
```

And here is what I've tried in the Post Request:

```
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(serverName);
  
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"deviceId\":\"9006765C87CD29BC37447E490C4C91F819143376\",\"requestData\":\"{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":0}}}\"}");
 
  Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
  Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  Serial.print(http.getString());

  http.end();
```

Here is the response:

```
{"error_code":-10100,"msg":"JSON format error"}HTTP Response code: 200
```

***UPDATE***
I originally thought I would only need to pass the params but here is a version I have tried passing the method and params. I still get the same results, however.

```
String json =
"({"
"\"method\":\"passthrough\","
"\"params\":{"
"\"deviceId\":\"9006765C87CD29BC37447E490C4C91F819143376\","
"\"requestData\":\"{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":1}}}\""
"}"
"})";
```

Using this json string - I have tried passing `int httpResponseCode = http.POST(json);` but that doesn't work either and I get the same error. I'm assuming I need to convert this string to a Json array before passing to htt.Post?

Comment: You only post the inner `params` part. Where is the outer object? Where is `"method"` and the actual `"params"` specifier?

Comment: I have updated the question and included the outer object. Thanks

Comment: Think about what `requestData` really is... It's a string, with an embedded JSON object. Quotes inside the string needs to be double-escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `requestData` needs to escape the quotes within the string. Otherwise the payload that is sent is malformed JSON with the value of `requestData` terminated too early.

This can be done with:

```
http.POST("{\"method\":\"passthrough\",\"params\":{\"deviceId\":\"9006765C87CD29BC37447E490C4C91F819143376\",\"requestData\":\"{\\\"system\\\":{\\\"set_relay_state\\\":{\\\"state\\\":0}}}\"}}";);
```

Or alternatively using a raw string literal:

```
http.POST(R"({"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"9006765C87CD29BC37447E490C4C91F819143376","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":0}}}"}})");
```

Comment: I believe I should have included the method and outer object. I have updated the original questions. I tried your suggestion but get ```stray '\' in program``` Thanks

Comment: You're on the right track, but the whole body of `requestData` is a single string and thus the escsping of the quotes needs to be included (as they are strings inside a string).

Comment: @Shane I have updated the code with the other parameters and balanced the backslashes